# Flutter navigator is preventing my admob ads from showing

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

If I open my app, show a splash screen and then go to the main home page, my admob banner does not show, and the whole app freezes after a few seconds. But if I go directly from to the `HomePage`, bypassing the splash page, the banner shows no problem?

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]).then((_) {
    Admob.initialize('ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713');
    runApp(MyApp());
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      showPerformanceOverlay: false,
      // home: SplashPage(),//ads do not show
      home: HomePage(),//ads show no problem
    );
  }
}

class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(// or with .push yields the same outcome
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return HomePage();
              },
              settings: RouteSettings(isInitialRoute: true),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Splash page'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('Home Page'),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 60,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            AdmobBanner(
              adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
              adSize: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening? Something is not going from the `SplashPage` through to the `HomePage` to allow the banner to show.

Comment: You can try this (https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob) library, an official from Google Admob Team

Comment: @secret35 There's no problem with the `admob_flutter` plugin, I have it working on other apps released in the app store. It's also working here in this app if I bypass the splash page.